# Compilation of MAX_HS solver with IBM CPLEX

Tags: linux, cplex, sat

i'm trying to get started with a max-sat solver named: MAX_HS.

The documentation is only a readme file, is not so much but it's clear what you have to do:
https://github.com/fbacchus/MaxHS

I've installed CPLEX library from IBM and configured the file as indicated in the documentation, but when I compile i'm getting an error, this is my terminal log:

```
\\install -d /usr/local/include/maxhs
install -d /usr/local/include/minisat
for dir in maxhs/core maxhs/ifaces maxhs/ds maxhs/utils; do \
  install -d /usr/local/include/$dir ; \
        done
for dir in minisat/mtl minisat/utils minisat/core minisat/simp; do \
  install -d /usr/local/include/$dir ; \
done
for h in minisat/mtl/Alg.h minisat/mtl/Map.h minisat/mtl/Alloc.h minisat/mtl/Vec.h minisat/mtl/Rnd.h minisat/mtl/Sort.h minisat/mtl/IntMap.h minisat/mtl/Queue.h minisat/mtl/IntTypes.h minisat/mtl/Heap.h minisat/mtl/XAlloc.h minisat/core/SolverTypes.h minisat/core/Dimacs.h minisat/core/Solver.h minisat/utils/System.h minisat/utils/ParseUtils.h 
minisat/utils/Options.h minisat/simp/SimpSolver.h  ;
    do \
     install -m 644 $h /usr/local/include/$h ; \
done
for h in maxhs/core/Bvars.h maxhs/core/Dimacs.h maxhs/core/MaxSolverTypes.h maxhs/core/Assumptions.h maxhs/core/Wcnf.h maxhs/core/MaxSolver.h maxhs/ifaces/miniSatSolver.h maxhs/ifaces/GreedySolver.h maxhs/ifaces/Cplex.h maxhs/ifaces/greedySatSolver.h maxhs/ifaces/muser.h maxhs/ifaces/SatSolver.h maxhs/ds/Packed.h maxhs/utils/io.h maxhs/utils/Params.h maxhs/utils/hash.h  ; 
   do \
      install -m 644 $h /usr/local/include/$h ; \
done
install -d /usr/local/lib
install -m 644 build/release/lib/libmaxhs.a /usr/local/lib
Linking Binary: build/release/bin/maxhs
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_memory_patched.o): In function `mkl_serv_set_memory_limit':
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x5a9): undefined reference to `dlopen'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x5ca): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x618): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x62e): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x739): undefined reference to `dlerror'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to `dlopen'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x840): undefined reference to `dlopen'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x856): undefined reference to `dlerror'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x91a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x922): undefined reference to `dlerror'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x937): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x962): undefined reference to `dlerror'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x972): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_memory.c:(.text+0x98d): undefined reference to `dlerror'
...
...
...
64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_semaphore.o): In function `_Init_MKL_Loader':
mkl_semaphore.c:(.text+0x4ed): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(libc_is_static_interface.o): In function `mkl_serv_libc_is_static':
libc_is_static_interface.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(load_library_HOST.o): In function `mkl_ueaa_prv_load_backend_lib':
load_library.c:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `dlopen'
load_library.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
load_library.c:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
load_library.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
load_library.c:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
load_library.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(load_library_HOST.o):load_library.c:(.text+0x2bc): more undefined references to `dlvsym' follow
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a(mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib_HOST.o): In function `mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib':
mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib.c:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `dlopen'
mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `dlsym'
mkl_aa_fw_load_orsl_lite_lib.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'build/release/bin/maxhs' failed
make: *** [build/release/bin/maxhs] Error 1
```

Really don't know what can cause the error as the library are the official licensed IBM cplex library and the only setup is the one who assign the right path to the IBM library. I guess i've done correctly this step as when the path was wrong and no IBM library was found i was getting another error.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CPLEX 12.8 you have to link with the dynamic linker library. You can see this in the example makefiles shipped with CPLEX. Looking at the `Makefile` in the MaxHS git repository, you could try changing the following line (this has not been tested):

```
MAXHS_LDFLAGS  = -Wall -lz -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -lcplex -lpthread
```

to:

```
MAXHS_LDFLAGS  = -Wall -lz -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -lcplex -lpthread -ldl
```

If that works, you should consider creating an issue for the maintainers of MaxHS.

Alternately, you could install an older version of CPLEX (e.g., 12.7.1).